# Override attributes that have to be serialized

Tags: c#, inheritance, xml-serialization

I wonder if it is possible to override a member of a class but also to serialize this attribute as if it were the "original" attribute.

To clear out what I mean I show you a short piece of code:

```
class Foo {  
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Order = 2)]
    public string area;
}
class Bar : Foo {
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(ElementName = "totalArea", Order = 2)]
    public new area{
        get{return "a new implementation of area";}
        set{}
    }
}

class Program {
    public static void main(...) {
        Foo foo = new Bar();
        foo.area = "whatever";
    }
}
```

So what I want is to give the attribute a new name. Ofc I could simply add a new attribute totalArea to the Bar´s class-definition, but that would double the amount of members which could become somehow confusing if you deal with bigger objects. Moreover since I am never sure of which exact subclass a given object is I do not know if it supports this extra-attribute "totalArea". So I want to simply use the "area"-attribute and the serializer decides which definition of the attribute to use.

Is this possible?

Comment: "but that would double the amount of members which could become somehow confusing" - honestly, if you are re-declaring members (`new`, etc) rather than using polymorphism, and if you are changing the element-names based on the position in the hierarchy - then it is *already* unnecessarily confusing... What is the *purpose* here? What is the thing that you are trying to *achieve*? (which is different from *what you are trying to code*; I mean: what is the intended end result here)

Comment: Ok, I´ll try to explain in a different manner: The class Bar also defines some other attributes. These attributes themself are objects that also have an area, so I come to some name-conflicts in the resulting XML (however, it´s no syntatically error inside the XML). This is why I wanted to rename the attribute in the XML...

Comment: Frankly, it sounds to me that in reality there isn't actually an inheritance relationship here, and that they should be entirely separate DTOs - the `new` is a good clue to this. You can, however, probably do it via conditional serialization - one moment

Answer (score 0):

Just implement `IXmlSerializable` interface to `Foo` class and override `WriteXml` method with any logic what you want.

Comment: This is rarely a good idea, IMHO - it isn't the most intuitive of APIs, and most implementations tend to make a mess of it - plus it completely destroys any discovery / metadata tools. Yes, it'll work ... ish; but it would be preferable to understand what the OP wants to *achieve*, and help them write the correct model for their scenario *without* custom serialization

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Unfortunetly the Foo-class is out of my control so I won´t be able to simply implement an own serialization.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I would advise that unrelated to serialization: re-declaring members is really confusing and contrary. One of the few times that this is relevant would be if the data-type changes between implementations, but that isn't the case here. It genuinely looks to me like `virtual` would be more appropriate - or even perhaps that they should be entirely separate DTO models.

However, we might consider conditional serialization; for example:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
public class Foo
{
    [XmlElement("area", Order = 2)]
    public virtual string Area { get; set; }

    [Browsable(false), EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
    public virtual bool ShouldSerializeArea()
    {
        return true;
    }
}
public class Bar : Foo
{
    [Browsable(false), EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
    public override bool ShouldSerializeArea()
    {
        return false;
    }

    [XmlElement("totalArea", Order = 2)]
    public string TotalArea
    {
        get { return Area; }
        set { Area = value; }
    }
}
static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        new XmlSerializer(typeof(Foo)).Serialize(Console.Out, new Foo { Area = "hello" });
        Console.WriteLine();
        new XmlSerializer(typeof(Bar)).Serialize(Console.Out, new Bar { Area = "world" });
    }
}
```